# moving script from unix to linux bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that I'm moving from a Solaris 11.3 environment to Oracle Linux 6.9 (used for exporting databases).  After updating various variables and paths the script runs correctly except for one section.

What it's supposed to do is check the target directory for other exports and delete those in excess of the indicated keep setting (in this case it's 1).  When the 'cleanup' section of the script runs it's properly identifying the files, but not removing them, indicating 'binary operator expected'.

The following is the section of the script that isn't working correctly:

```
FILE_MASK="${ORACLE_SID}_*.dmp.gz" 
counter=0
if [[ -f ${EXP_DIR}/${FILE_MASK} ]]; then
  #
  # count the files (don't use ls command because it has a limit)
  #
  for CNT in $EXP_DIR/$FILE_MASK
  do
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
  done
  count=`expr $counter - $KEEP_FILES + 1`
  #
  counter=0
  for I in $EXP_DIR/$FILE_MASK
  do
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    FILE_NAME=`basename $I`
    echo "${JOBNAME_SHORT}:  File = ${EXP_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}"
    if [[ ${counter} -lt ${count} ]] ; then
      echo "${JOBNAME_SHORT}:    Removing file."
      rm ${EXP_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}
    fi
  done
```

The error returned is:

/home/oracle/scripts/oraexpdp.sh: line 241: [: /u07/exports/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx_2018111413.dmp.gz: binary operator expected

Line 241 of the script is the line starting with 'if' above.

In searching for a fix there was a reference to using double-bracketing ([[ ]]) with bash, and that still returns the same error.  What do I need to tweak to get this working correctly?

Many Thanks!

Harvey

Comment: What is the first line of the script? Is it `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` (or something else)?

Comment: From what I can tell, when you're setting `FILE_MASK="${ORACLE_SID}_*.dmp.gz"` you're using a `*` wildcard? This is taken as a literal, not a wildcard in "double quotes" you'd reference it differently but regex would be `.*` I can't actually see if you closed your `if` loop with `fi`, so maybe just list the relevant bit of the script

Comment: The first line is !bin/sh

Comment: The script has three similar sections looking for different specific files.  The closing fi is actually after the third section.  There is an else followed by an fi that would be after the done statement above.

Answer (score 0):

`[[ -f ${EXP_DIR}/${FILE_MASK} ]]` is going to give a group of files because of wild card bash substitution, so wont evaluate that a file exists.

In the case where there are no matching files `${EXP_DIR}/${FILE_MASK}` will be wildcard string still.

Assuming that `KEEP_FILES` will always be 1 or more, you could probably just remove the `if [[ -f ${EXP_DIR}/${FILE_MASK} ]]` as in the case of no files, it wouldn't delete anything, as there would be just the wildcard name,

in the case of multiple files, it will behave as normal.